# running a script from github

Tags: parsing, github

I've been learning python for a few weeks, so please be easy on me. I'm running a script from github

https://github.com/arosen93/ptable_trends/

Really not sure what I'm doing wrong - I should just need to edit this line

```
parser.add_argument('filename',type=str,help='Filename (with extension) of ''CSV-formatted data')
```

change to;

```
parser.add_argument('C:/Users/PycharmProjects/periodictable/ionization_energies.csv',type=str,help='Filename (with extension) of 'CSV-formatted data')
```

Constantly get error messages

> main.py: error: the following arguments are required: C:/Users/LE403
> mk2/PycharmProjects/periodictable/ionization_energies.csv

Comment: Your error is from main.py, but there is no main.py in that project. Could you show us your main.py and the line the error is coming from?

Comment: I figured out what's gone wrong and updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69226505/14660).

Answer (score 1):

***tl;dr***: You should run `ptable_trends.py --filename C:/Users/PycharmProjects/periodictable/ionization_energies.csv` from your command line. You should not have to edit the code.

`parser.add_argument` tells the program what arguments it accepts.

```
parser.add_argument('filename',type=str,help='Filename (with extension) of '
        'CSV-formatted data')
```

This calls the [add_argument method of the class ArgumentParser from the argparse library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method). It says the program takes the argument `--filename` which is a string and the help message about that argument tells you it is a "Filename (with extension) of CSV-formatted data".

If you write in your main.py...

```
parser.add_argument('C:/Users/PycharmProjects/periodictable/ionization_energies.csv',type=str,help='Filename (with extension) of 'CSV-formatted data')
```

That says your main.py takes an argument of `--C:/Users/PycharmProjects/periodictable/ionization_energies.csv` which is a string to a "Filename (with extension) of 'CSV-formatted data" which doesn't make any sense.

---

There is an escaped quote in the original, the `''`.

```
>>> 'Filename (with extension) of ''CSV-formatted data'
'Filename (with extension) of CSV-formatted data'
```

You lost the escape.

```
>>> 'Filename (with extension) of 'CSV-formatted data'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    'Filename (with extension) of 'CSV-formatted data'
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Your quotes are "unbalanced". The quote should probably be removed entirely.